# Clarification on launchd plist Program and ProgramArguments usage

Tags: launchd

Can somebody please clarify how launchd's `Program` and `ProgramArguments` configuration parameters should be used? I tried to register a service which on the command line I'd start like this:

```
$ /foo/bar/baz/python /foo/bar/baz/service start
```

I have tried divvying that up in various ways for launchd:

```xml
<key>Program</key>
<string>/foo/bar/baz/python</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/foo/bar/baz/service</string>
    <string>start</string>
</array>
```

or

```xml
<key>Program</key>
<string>/foo/bar/baz/python</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/foo/bar/baz/service start</string>
</array>
```

or

```xml
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/foo/bar/baz/python</string>
    <string>/foo/bar/baz/service</string>
    <string>start</string>
</array>
```

or

```xml
<key>Program</key>
<string>/bin/bash</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>/foo/bar/baz/python /foo/bar/baz/service start</string>
</array>
```

and just about any other variation that would seem to make sense. The service always failed with various different errors though. The only thing that worked was to create a .sh script with the exact line and run *that* via launchd.

So, to understand launchd services once and for all: How does launchd use these two configuration parameters, how would I replicate my bash command with them and what is the difference between both?
Or am I perhaps just stumbling across a problem of running this particular service with and without some environment variables which exist when executing it via bash? The service itself did not provide any useful output.

I have consulted the [`execvp(3)` manual entry](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/execvp.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/execvp) as advised in `launchd.plist(5)`, but it did not really further my understanding.

Answer (score 4):

If `Program` is specified, it will always be the program executed, even if `ProgramArguments` has been specified as well.

```
<key>Program</key>
<string>/foo/bar/baz/python</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/foo/bar/baz/python</string>
    <string>/foo/bar/baz/service</string>
    <string>start</string>
</array>
```

In this case the first element in `ProgramArguments` is not actually evaluated, but it is passed as `argv[0]` to the program being executed. Usually this is not needed, but it has its uses. For instance the program may inspect `argv[0]` and run in a different mode depending on this value.

For everything else it is sufficient to only use `ProgramArguments`. This job definition works exactly as the one above:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/foo/bar/baz/python</string>
    <string>/foo/bar/baz/service</string>
    <string>start</string>
</array>
```